# Generalisation of the first fundamental form to smooth manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, surfaces

When we study Differential Geometry of surfaces, we define something called the first fundamental form. It is a symmetric bilinear form on the tangent space at a point on the surface.

Moreover, I know from Linear Algebra that the determinant of this first fundamental form (when we choose a parametrisation for our surface, and represent this bilinear form in a matrix form) is exactly the *Gram determinant*, which is equal to the square of the volume of a parallelepiped in this tangent space.

Seeing this connection, and also considering the fact that I know more about smooth manifolds compare to my knowledge on surfaces, is there any generalisation of the concept of first fundamental form to smooth manifolds ?

Comment: A smooth manifold with a positive definite "first fundamental form" is called a Riemannian manifold.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I heard Riemannian manifolds a lot, but never look at what it is exactly; your comment just blew my mind.